# problems starting service that runs a bash script that in turn runs a python script

Tags: python-3.x, service

I have the following service file, enable, and start files located in /home/pi/poolboy/service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Pool Boy
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/poolboy/start
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/poolboy
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have an "enable" script to install it:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo cp /home/pi/poolboy/service/poolboy.service /lib/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable poolboy.service
```

I have a "start" script to start the service:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl start poolboy.service
```

the actual start script that runs the application (and is called by the service) is located in /home/pi/poolboy:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
VENV=venv

echo 'checking for ' $VENV
if [ ! -d $VENV ]
then
  echo $VENV ' does not exist... initially creating it'
  python3 -m venv $VENV
  echo 'activating the virtual environment'
  source venv/bin/activate
  echo 'installing libraries from requirements.txt'
  pip3 install -r requirements.txt
else
  source $VENV/bin/activate
fi

echo 'starting...'
sudo $VENV/bin/python3 poolboy.py --standalone
```

After running the enable script I run the start script.  I get the following output in my /var/log/syslog:

```
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[4980]: poolBoy.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[4980]: poolBoy.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[4981]: poolBoy.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[4981]: poolBoy.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jun 19 22:10:43 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[4982]: poolBoy.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[4982]: poolBoy.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[4984]: poolBoy.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[4984]: poolBoy.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: poolBoy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 22:10:44 poolboy systemd[1]: Failed to start Pool Boy.
```

After replacing poolBoy with poolboy, it looks better, but the application is still not starting:

```
Jun 20 11:09:28 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:09:28 poolboy start[1373]: checking for  venv
Jun 20 11:09:28 poolboy start[1373]: starting...
Jun 20 11:09:28 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Succeeded.
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Service RestartSec=30s expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 12.
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy start[1447]: checking for  venv
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy start[1447]: starting...
Jun 20 11:09:58 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Succeeded.
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Service RestartSec=30s expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 13.
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy start[1521]: checking for  venv
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy start[1521]: starting...
Jun 20 11:10:28 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Succeeded.
Jun 20 11:10:58 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Service RestartSec=30s expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 20 11:10:58 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 14.
Jun 20 11:10:58 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:10:58 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:10:59 poolboy start[1595]: checking for  venv
Jun 20 11:10:59 poolboy start[1595]: starting...
Jun 20 11:10:59 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Succeeded.
Jun 20 11:11:01 poolboy kernel: [  458.537483]
Jun 20 11:11:01 poolboy kernel: [  458.537513] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_dequeue:639: Timed out waiting for FSM NP transfer to complete on 5
Jun 20 11:11:13 poolboy kernel: [  470.441646]
Jun 20 11:11:13 poolboy kernel: [  470.441682] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_dequeue:639: Timed out waiting for FSM NP transfer to complete on 5
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Service RestartSec=30s expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15.
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy systemd[1]: Stopped Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy systemd[1]: Started Pool Boy.
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy start[1670]: checking for  venv
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy start[1670]: starting...
Jun 20 11:11:29 poolboy systemd[1]: poolboy.service: Succeeded.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So I found I had a mis-spelling (corrected above) poolBoy should be poolboy in the service files.  Now, when I run  /home/pi/poolboy/service/enable, then  /home/pi/poolboy/service/start  I get the syslog messages above (looks good) but the application doesn't start unless I run it manually with /home/pi/poolboy/start

Answer (score 0):

duh... my /home/pi/poolboy/start script had an & in the last line :-/
Now working with the above files